# Modular of big numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I have this question which I have trouble comprehending.

I am asked to find

$$111 + 11113 + 1111115 \mod{11}.$$

Apparently, according the results the answer is 8. But I just can't see how. I have some what knowledge regarding modular exponentials. However cannot see how apply this here.

If anyone could shed some light upon this, it would be very appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you are overthinking the problem.  You could add the three numbers and then reduce modulo $11$, but the nice thing about modulo arithmetic is that you can also begin by reducing each summand modulo $11$.  Try that and see how far you get.

Comment: The answer is not $8$, it is $9$. You can check that $102030 \cdot 11 + 9 -  (111 + 11113 + 1111115) = 0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that $111 = 110 + 1 = 11\cdot 10 + 1 \equiv_{11} 1$.  So if a number begins with two identical digits, you can strip them away without changing the value modulo 11.  In your case 
$$111 + 11113 + 1111115 \equiv_{11} 1 + 113 + 11115 \equiv_{11} 1 + 3 + 115 \equiv_{11} 1 + 3 + 5 = 9.$$

Comment: whoops, fixed now.

Comment: Appreciate all the help. The teacher probably did make a mistake by saying that it was equal to mod 8.

Answer (score 3):

The congruence class of a number modulo $11$ is the alternating sum of its digits (in base $10$), starting from the right. Hence:
$$111+11113+1111115\equiv 1+3+5=9 \mod 11.$$